# Use column values of dataframe as index and columns name

Tags: pandas

I'm working with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Client_ID   Product_ID   Cost
0      4            1         40
1      4            2         32
2      5            1         38
3      6            7         89
4      7            3         21
5      4            5         45
6      2            5         23
7      2            4         71
8      5            8         11
9      7            8         14
```

For each couple `'Client_ID, Product_ID'` there is only one occurence/row in the dataframe.

I want to build a dataframe where the `Product_ID` is the index and where the the column names are the client names while the cost become the value in each cell, it would look like this:

```
                     Client_ID
Product_ID    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
   1          x   x   x  40  38   x   x
   2          x   x   x  32   x   x   x
   3          x   x   x   x   x   x  21
   4          x  71   x   x   x   x   x
   5          x  23   x  45   x   x   x
   6          x   x   x   x   x   x   x
   7          x   x   x   x   x  89   x
   8          x   x   x   x  11   x  14
   9          x   x   x   x   x   x   x
  10          x   x   x   x   x   x   x
```

I tried to achieve this by doing this:

```
df.pivot(index='Product_ID', columns='Client_ID')
```

But it didn't work, I tried then making `Product_ID` the index first and then do the pivot:

```
df = df.set_index('Product_ID')
df.index.name = None
df.pivot(columns='Client_ID')
```

No success neither.

Does somebody know how to achieve such a thing?

Thank you for your help.

### Edit

The Product_ID values are strings.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='Product_ID', columns='Client_ID', values='Cost').reindex(columns=np.arange(1, df.Client_ID.max() + 1)).fillna('x')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) + [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add missing rows/ columns:

```
#reindex by union of columns
a = np.union1d(df['Client_ID'],df['Product_ID'])
df = df.pivot(index='Product_ID', columns='Client_ID', values='Cost')
       .reindex(index=a, columns=a)
print (df)
Client_ID    1     2   3     4     5     6     7   8
Product_ID                                          
1          NaN   NaN NaN  40.0  38.0   NaN   NaN NaN
2          NaN   NaN NaN  32.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
3          NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  21.0 NaN
4          NaN  71.0 NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
5          NaN  23.0 NaN  45.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
6          NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
7          NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN  89.0   NaN NaN
8          NaN   NaN NaN   NaN  11.0   NaN  14.0 NaN
```

Or:

```
#1 to max value of columns
b = range(1,df['Client_ID'].max()+1)
a = range(1,df['Product_ID'].max()+1)
df = df.pivot(index='Product_ID', columns='Client_ID', values='Cost')
       .reindex(index=a, columns=b)
print (df)
Client_ID    1     2   3     4     5     6     7
Product_ID                                      
1          NaN   NaN NaN  40.0  38.0   NaN   NaN
2          NaN   NaN NaN  32.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
3          NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  21.0
4          NaN  71.0 NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5          NaN  23.0 NaN  45.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
6          NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
7          NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN  89.0   NaN
8          NaN   NaN NaN   NaN  11.0   NaN  14.0
```

Detail:

```
print (df.pivot(index='Product_ID', columns='Client_ID', values='Cost'))
Client_ID      2     4     5     6     7
Product_ID                              
1            NaN  40.0  38.0   NaN   NaN
2            NaN  32.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
3            NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  21.0
4           71.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5           23.0  45.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
7            NaN   NaN   NaN  89.0   NaN
8            NaN   NaN  11.0   NaN  14.0
```

Last if necessary replace `NaN`s, but get mixed values - numeric with strings:

```
df = df.fillna('x')
```

Comment: I have a constraint that I forgot to share, it is that the Product_ID is a string :/

Comment: So what about `(df.pivot(index='Product_ID', columns='Client_ID', values='Cost').reindex(columns=b)` ?

Comment: I don't understand what the .reindex method does, is it necessary? When I run your 3rd solution, the one liner alone, it works straight away...

Comment: Hmmm, it is if need add missing rows, columns to data. If not, just use `pivot` only.

Comment: But if want change it in question, then is necessary remove answer, because dupe...

Comment: It is not dupe, because pivot + `reindex`

Comment: ok, so the reindex step is necessary if I want to achieve the result that I want. But from what I see it just rearranges the Client_ID in an ascendant order.

Comment: No, you are wrong. pivot always create unique index and columns values. Reindex is necessary if need `nice consecutives values` in index. So if `pivot` return `index=[1,3,5]` then for `index=[1,2,3,4,5]` need `df.reindex(index=range(1, 6))`